# Is there way to know when last logged in and out?

Tags: login, logs, user-account

Is it possible to know when I last time logged in and out?

I would prefer to access this information from Terminal, but a GUI tool is also okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Terminal application, type `last` and voilà, there is your answer!

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I want!

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it. 